# How to check in java if 5<10>5<10 to n

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, numbers, compare

How can I check for example from an array if `5<10>5<10`

Code:

```
int[] arr = {5,10,5,10,5,10,5};

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j < arr.length - i; j++) {
        if(arr[j-1] < arr[j] && arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
            System.out.println("ok!");
        }
    }
}
```

For now I have this, but it's wrong.

Comment: is it supposed to be greater then less, then greater? or alternate 5,10?

Comment: yes greater then less, then greater

Comment: Suppose you edit that into your question and your title. Nobody knows what you're talking about the way it is now.

Answer (score 3):

You only have a 1-dimensional array, so you should be able to do this with one loop.  Your inner loop looks close.  Try this:

```
int[] arr = {5,10,5,10,5,10,5};

for(int j = 1; j < arr.length-1; j++){
    if(arr[j-1] < arr[j] && arr[j] > arr[j+1]){
        System.out.println("ok!");
    }
}
```

This starts with the second element and ends with the second-to-last element, and checks the elements on each side for the condition you defined.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming you have at least 2 members in the array (you can check that before):

```
boolean isOk = true;

for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i+=2){
       isOk = isOk && (arr[i] > arr[i-1]) && (arr.length == i+1 || (arr[i] > arr[i+1]));
    } 
}

if(isOk) {
    System.out.println("ok!");
}
```